# Why isn't Pyinotify able to watch a dir?

Tags: watch, inotify, pyinotify

I would like **Pyinotify** to watch a templates directory, which has subfolders, but I'm getting this error:

```
DIRECTORY /home/project/templates
[Pyinotify ERROR] add_watch: cannot watch /home/project/templates WD=-1
[Pyinotify ERROR] add_watch: cannot watch /home/project/templates/dir1 WD=-1
[Pyinotify ERROR] add_watch: cannot watch /home/project/templates/dir2 WD=-1
Waiting for stuff to happen...
```

I've found answers such as using a unicode directory name or using other programs which use inotify, but each is too specific.

What generally causes this error?

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/13751/kernel-inotify-watch-limit-reached/13757#13757 Possibly the best answer I have found.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Increase the maximum number or watches:

```
sudo sysctl -n -w fs.inotify.max_user_watches=16384
```

Reference: http://github.com/seb-m/pyinotify/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions

**ASIDE**

If you're looking for notification tools, also try http://github.com/peterbe/python-gorun.